# How to have more than 12 blocks in a section in Shopify Online Store 2.0?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Recently Shopify released **Dawn theme(Online store 2.0)** where they use **JSON templates**. But I noticed a section can have **12 blocks at most** even tho max_block is not set in section schema. Is there any way to have more than 12 blocks in a section?

[image]

Comment: You can't, as per new norms they list the blocks to this number, but now you add sections everywhere into theme 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE

Shopify upped the limit of 16 to **50 blocks per section**! The documentation now reflects that change: https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#max_blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of 16 blocks per section. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#max_blocks).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That's the old figure. Now it's 50 limit. Why is there a limit for JSON stored data, who knows :-(

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there’s a **limit of 16 blocks** per section. You can specify a lower limit with the max_blocks in **Online Store 2.0** theme (like Dawn).

Comment: Limit is 16 blocks not 12.